# Is it possible, today, to read avi files on Aquaris m10?

Tags: video, aquaris, m10, avi

What I mainly do with a tablet : Browse internet, read epub books, read emails, and watch movies. I am naive, I was not expecting to get everything with Ubuntu touch, but at least watching my avi movies :-(
Is there an app today, for that?. The one provided with the tablet is not reading avi.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I watch them by using the movies scope. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Open-World said: "I watch them by using the movies scope. Have you tried it?"

Comment: Yes I tried. Is there another app ?

Comment: Yes I tried. Is there another app ? In fact it's working with small avi files, but not with movies of 1.2 Gb. I get a message like "unable to connect with the reader in the background"

Comment: for info, I tried to change the format with avidemux : MP4 and OGM are not read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, avi files stored on the memory card can be played from the video scope. Tried and it worked.